# Create random groups of 3 rows in R

Tags: r, split, dplyr, sample

I'm trying to create as many random groups from a dataset as possible. My data is kind of complicated to explain so I'll use `iris` for my example.

In `iris`, the `Species` variable contains 3 unique values: `setosa`, `versicolor`, and `virginica`.

1. I want to randomize and group the dataset into groups of 3 rows, with each group containing unique Species only. (eg. 1 of each Species)
2. Each group must have a `cumsum(Sepal.Width >= 10)`
3. Create a new `ID` that identifies each group.

So far I've tried using the *dplyr* function `group_by()` and `sample_n()`. Also `split()` and `sample()`, but can't seem to get the desired result.

Using `split()` I think might be the wrong way to do it. I was trying to make it work along these lines with no luck.

```
split(unique(iris), sample(1:nrow(iris) %/% 3))
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What do you mean with "randomize"? you need to cumsum(Sepal.Width >= 10) a random sample of your original data?

Comment: @Robert Sorry, by randomize I mean "sample". In my original data I need to find the cumsum of the rows and ensure they meet certain criteria. I just thought it would be the same (and easier) to explain with iris.

Comment: Do you care about uniqueness? ie sampling with replacement?

Comment: @Vlo Yes, in my dataset I have many duplicate rows that I need preserved and grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#the sample
N=dim(iris)[1]
n=50 #sample size
set.seed(123)
si=iris[sample(N,n),c("Species","Sepal.Width")]

#the "cumsum"
lim=2.8 #for the conditional sum
Sepal.Width=sapply(split(si,si$Species),function(x)
   sum(x$Sepal.Width >= lim))
sol=data.frame(Species=names(Sepal.Width),Sepal.Width)
sol$ID=1:length(sol[,1])
sol
#               Species Sepal.Width ID
# setosa         setosa          18  1
# versicolor versicolor           8  2
# virginica   virginica          14  3
```

Comment: Hi @Robert I'm looking to actually keep the entire dataframe and make groups of 3. So in your example, all 3 rows would have an ID of 1, then the next 3 have an ID of 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the problem. Here's how you could do it using dplyr

First, load some packages and add a unique ID for each row in the `iris` data.frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
iris = iris %>% mutate(Row.ID=1:n())
```

Then, let's split the Row.IDs according to species, and get a data.frame with all possible combinations of one row from each species

```
iris_split = split(iris$Row.ID, iris$Species)
combinations = do.call(expand.grid, iris_split)
```

Now, it's `dplyr` and `tidyr` time. Let's gather those combinations in a variable called `tmp`, join `tmp` with the rest of the `iris` data.frame and then filter according to the criteria.

```
tmp = combinations %>%
    mutate(Group.ID=1:n()) %>%
    gather(Var, Row.ID, -Group.ID) %>%
    select(-Var)

result = iris %>%
    inner_join(tmp) %>%
    group_by(Group.ID) %>%
    filter(sum(Sepal.Length) > 10) %>%
    arrange(Group.ID)
```

The `result` data.frame should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for the response. I was unable to get that code to work. In ``gather(Var, Row.ID, -Group.ID) %>%`` it's saying "object 'Var' not found"